# Systemd Automation -- Run Python Script on Boot via Service

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd

I've put together an automated temperature checking script, written in Python, that notifies me if it detects a value outside of a given range, with the intention of running it on a headless Raspberry Pi. In researching how to do this, it quickly became apparent that the most commonly suggested method is to use Systemd. Unfortunately, I have been unable to recreate the tutorials I've been working through for most of the day, and have decided it's time to solicit help.

I'm not sure what information to provide here, since the Python script works totally fine by itself. That said, this is what I ended up with when attempting to create a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Temp Check Script
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u TempCheck.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/TempCheck
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here are the errors I receive when I check the status:

```
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Start request repeated too quickly.
Failed with result "exit-code"
Failed to start Temp Check Script
```

I've tried my best to ask critical questions while doing this to better understand what each of these things really means, but this is day 1 of using bash/systemd, so, if you're wondering why exactly I did a particular thing, the answer will definitely be either ignorance or because a tutorial told me to. Speaking of which, here is the one this service is based off of --> https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

Thanks so much for your help, I really do appreciate it!

Edit:

When running:

```
journalctl -u TempCheck.service
```

I receive a few new things, including:

```
python3[404]: /usr/bin/python3 can't open file 'main.py': [Erno 2] No such file or directory
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'/
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Stopped Temp Check Script
systemd[1]: TempCheck.service: Started Temp Check Script
```

This repeats a few times.

I feel I should clarify, I have since continued reviewing tutorials, etc. and modified the service to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Temp Check Script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/TempCheck/TempCheck.py
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/TempCheck
StartLimitIntervalSec=10
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the newly provided, extended error messages are from that service, I believe

Edit 2:

I realized one of the tutorials I was following had asked me to include:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
```

At the top of my script. I have since removed it. Now I see that the script is supposedly running, but I am not receiving any notifications that would indicate it is doing what it should be (again, odd because it totally works when run in an IDE, as well as directly from the command line). Check again, however, and we are back to a failed status, this time with the initial error:

```
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Start request repeated too quickly.
Failed with result "exit-code"
Failed to start Temp Check Script
```

Edit 3: In trying with crontab, I have also been unsuccessful. Not sure why this is the case, since it's basically doing the same thing as when I invoke from the command line directly, and, when using CLI, it works fine. This says to me that there is nothing wrong with the script, and a good chance there is nothing really wrong with systemd or crontab, but there is something weird going on between systemd/crontab and the script. I've double and triple checked the directories I've fed it, and they're correct. I'm completely out of ideas here.

Solution: Don't try to use environmental variables in the script, just declare them outright. This is the best I've got, though I'm going to keep looking for ways of referencing environmental variables. Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `journalctl -u <your_unit_name>` show?

Comment: So do you have some file named `main.py` that `TempCheck.py` is using? Check `systemctl status TempCheck.service`

Comment: I don't believe so. The only place that might be coming from is the fact that I have it referencing some environmental variables I created, and those are in a different directory. Also, see the new edit I made, that might help some

Comment: Your problem has little to nothing to do with systemd, you'd have the same issues with Cron. What's the error Python throws now that you're actually executing the script?

Comment: Python does not throw an error and I'm ~100% sure there's not a problem with the script. I have successfully run it from the command line without a problem using python3 /dir/to/file.py

To your point though, I'm not seeing success with crontab either

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the interval between service restarts. You can do so by setting the directive `StartLimitIntervalSec=`.
After setting this, don't forget to reload the service daemon with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Unfortunately this does not seem to have solved the problem :-( I set the interval to 30 seconds and am receiving the same errors. The only change is now status=2. Thoughts?